# htaccess to open file with encoded filename

Tags: apache, .htaccess, urlencode

I have a website where users can upload files, if they upload a file with a special character in the filename the filename will be encoded (for example: iordănescu.pdf will become iord%C4%83nescu.pdf)

This causes some problems to be able to open these files from a link on the website, I can't open the file with `website.com/iordănescu.pdf` or `website.com/iord%C4%83nescu.pdf` it only works when the encoded filename is encoded (so double encoded) like this: `website.com/iord%25C4%2583nescu.pdf`

This is my htaccess file in the folder where the files are uploaded to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove language from url for file viewing
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z]{2}/frontend/files/jobs/(.*)$          frontend/files/jobs/$1 [B,L,R=301]
```

This will redirect to: `website.com/iordănescu.pdf` and will give the following error: **The requested URL /frontend/files/jobs/iordÄƒnescu.pdf was not found on this server.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try json encode for special character. 
Example:

```
//special character json_encode
protected function _normJsonStr($str){
    $str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/i', create_function('$m', 'return chr(hexdec($m[1])-1072+224);'), $str);
    return iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $str);
}

//convert utf8
protected function _utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = $this->_utf8ize($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
}
```

Use: `return $this->_normJsonStr(json_encode($this->_utf8ize($data)));`

Comment: I want to see if it is possible with htaccess first since the URLs are on different pages in the backend, automated emails when a file gets uploaded, ... so it would be quite a bit of work to change all these pages with a function like this.